# GPO Windows Update Settings to schedule installs and reboots

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, group-policy

I need to set GPO settings on a domain to schedule the install & reboot for windows updates. The device is public facing so don't want any pop's on screen and want it all to happen out of hours.

I have set configured automatic updates to auto download and schedule the install. Set the install time to be 20:00 every Monday with active hours to be between 8am -7pm.

However the issue is that I am noticing from the event log that it is still installing updates during the active hours.

If anyone can provide any tips, that would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Which policy settings do you have configured for updates? Run a `gpresult` report and verify the schedule is getting set properly (correct time zone, etc). If you are using a service like WSUS, then update deadlines can override for example

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be much more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Since it is on a domain, you can disable active hours and fully manage the updates yourself via SCCM or Intune or WSUS, and define the update methods, policies, and scripts that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The devices are on a domain and the updates are pulled straight from the web instead of wsus as they are excluded from receiving the wsus settings as they dont fall in line with other devices on the domain so cant receive the same set of policies.